# Navigating through Bootstrap Table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Bootstrap Table where i want to go through the rows with my arrow keys.

```
$("#items").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();

    active = $('#items').find('#items-table tr.bg-info').removeClass('bg-info'); //removes alle highlighed rows
    var x = active.index();
    if (e.which === 9) //tab
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        //mark first One 
    }
    else if (e.which === 40) //runter
    {
        x--;
    }
    else if (e.which === 38)// hoch
    {
        x++;
    }
    active = $('#items').find('#items-table tr').eq(x).addClass('bg-info');
});
```

first i want to jump into the first row.
I had something like:

`active = $('#items').find('#items-table tr').first('tr').addClass('bg-info');`

but this selects the header `row` which i didn't.
And my last line where i want to select the `row` which fit to my `x` which is my `index` didn't work.

Need some advice how i can get it working.

Comment: maybe you could add sample html, and that js to jsfiddle :) it'd help us to edit your code

Comment: consider using `tabindex`, it's the method that makes form elements navigable by using the tab key.

Comment: If your table has a `tbody` tag you can use this `$('#items').find('#items-table tbody > tr')`

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH without `>` it finds every lower level element even if it's nested in some other element :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic That's the point ! select only child elements of table tbody's ! Am I missing something ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH sorry , didn't look at question correctly, your approach is ok.

Comment: Got it guys, thanks for your help. Will post my answer soon as i get time in the office